# Using object literal rather than switch statement

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

There is a lot of discussions and comments about best practices in **switch** and **if/else** statements. I have seen people saying that *we all should use object literal instead of switch* when it is possible.

So I've reproduced this case and [I went trough a little and simple test](http://jsperf.com/switch-from-switches) between a switch :

```js
(function(test){
    var bar;

    switch(bar) {
        case 1:
            bar = 'red';
            break;
        case 2:
            bar = 'blue';
            break;
        case 3:
            bar = 'yellow';
            break;
        case 4:
            bar = 'green';
            break;
        case 5:
            bar = 'black';
            break;
    }

    return bar;
})(5);
```

and passing trough an object literal :

```js
(function(test){
    return { 1: 'red', 2: 'blue', 3: 'yellow', 4: 'green', 5: 'black' }[ test ];
})(5);
```

After running this [test](http://jsperf.com/switch-from-switches), it seems evident that the switch statement is faster than calling the tested value in an object literal.

Is my test wrong ? What should I consider before using one or another method in this case ? Or maybe opinionated comments I've seen about this subject are just wrong and I should not try to bypass fundamentals...

Comment: Your test is fine; you are trading memory for speed (which you can almost always do). You may also be engaged in premature/micro-optimization. Further, with an object you cannot run arbitrary code (unless the values are functions that you then invoke, at the overhead of a function call). In general, strive first to optimize your _algorithms_, not your individual code calls.

Comment: Oh, wait, there is one problem with your test: you are re-instantiating the object literal during each new function call. Pre-allocate that object and try again. Also, note that with modern JIT JS runtimes heavily testing small loops of code like that will kick in instruction re-writing that may not be indicative of real-world performance.

Comment: @Phrogz http://jsperf.com/switch-from-switches/4; though I'm still not a fan of using object notation.

Comment: @Phrogz I see the problem there, but I think instantiating the object literal should be considered in the test, even in the loop, otherwise the second test would benefit of an object instance the other one do not need. I'm I right ?
By the way, I see what you mean about "real-life performances" in those kind of tests.

Comment: I also wanted to say, this is for sure just micro-optimisation.
The goal is not really optimizing my switch statement, it's just bumping on people says : why doing it this way is better ? Is it performances ? Or is it just verbose-less non-mainstream coding style... If there is a **real** difference, as small as it could be, I can change old habits in how I code javascript. Finally, this is not a problem, just details brought by some curiosity.

Comment: More alternatives to swtich, with a better test set. http://jsperf.com/switch-from-switches/13

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're likely seeing effects of scale:  A switch statement is `O(n)`, while a hash table lookup (presumably used to find methods in object literals) is (amortized) `O(1)`.  But Big-O measures only accurately describe how performance scales over really big inputs.  In your test, it's not surprising that five `if` statements are faster than a hash table lookup.

So basically:  *How many keys are you going to have?*  If you've only got five keys, you'll hit on average 2.5 per lookup, which you've shown to be faster than a single hash table lookup.  But what if you have 500?  That's an average of 250 `if` statements - still versus a *single* hash lookup.  The hash table (object literal) approach is almost assuredly better at that point.

But the ultimate answer?  everybody hates to hear this, but it's the only authoritative way:  Do the benchmark with your actual production code.  It's a pain, but then you know for sure.

Hope that helps!

**PS:**  This is leaving aside all considerations of coding style preference, but I really don't want to get into that...

Comment: Thanks @xavier-holt, this is a clear, objective and instructive answer.

Comment: I just want to note that Switch statements are O(logN) if the statements can be ordered by frequency.  Furthermore, I believe the major Jits optimize Switch statements when the key is an int or a String.

Answer (score 2):

Well I modified your code ([here](http://jsperf.com/switch-from-switches/2)) for you to see when object notion would be better.

Just as Xavier described, but it didn't have to go to about 500. Roughly 40 cases exposed the switch..

Another thing, besides the size of the **list** to note is that, in object notion the lookup for an integral would gain no benefit, while switch can optimize that bit.

Comment: Lookup for an "integral"? Sorry what is that in this context...did you mean "integer"?