# Any way to simplify long if else statement with < in conditions?

Tags: javascript

I have the following part of code, which I do not really like:

```
if (a < 2){
    b = 'somethingX';
} else if (a < 4){
    b = 'somethingY';
} else if (a < 6){
    ....;
} else {
    b = 'somethingZ';
}
```

I have something like 20 such if else statements and all of them consist of `(a < SomeNumber)` conditions. Result I am assigning to `b` can is not a function of `a` and `a < someNumber` is not in a regular interval.  I would like to simplify them, but can not come up with an adequate solution.

If I would have `(a === SomeNumber)` I would be able to do this easily with creating an object and accessing the value from this object (something [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13383798/1090562)), but here I have < sign. Is there any approach?

**P.S.** please do not suggest changing this to switch. I would like to make it easier to read, and based on my subjective opinion reading `switch` is on the same level as `if else`.

**P.S.2** people asked the reason for this logic. Basically I have a thin client which returns code for error messages. They grouped in some particular way. For example everything from 1 to 8 is because there is some problem with a user. From 9 to 21 because the key is not correct. Sometimes I do not need to notify a user the exact message, so because of the grouping I can just tell generic message. Why my server is not sending the message? It is as thin as possible, so sending 7 is better then a big string.

Comment: You might wanna use `switch` if you are gonna have 20 statements like that.

Comment: @indieblue thank you for comment. It reminded me that I forgot to write that I do not want to use switch (I updated my question)

Comment: switch is easier to read IMO.

Comment: @BOSS this is exactly why I added the word **subjective**

Comment: If the possible values for `b` are not automatically deducible or computable from the value of `a`, you will always need to explicit all the cases, don't you (whether with `if else`, `switch` or with `floor(a/2)` if your intervals are regular)?

Comment: @dgiugg result I am assigning to `b` can is not a function of `a` and `a < someNumber` is not in a regular interval.

Comment: How about creating an array of things you want to assign to `b` and loop trough it till you get the closest one?

Comment: @putvande thank you for suggestion, but this sounds more complicated than if/else. Actually I hoped for some magic with Object (similar to what I described in === case)

Comment: see my edit, by using a pre-filled array, you'll have a syntax like res = matchMap[value], so it's very readable.

Comment: "*b is not a function of a and someNumbers are not in a regular interval*" - wow, I'd like to hear details about that use case. It might be possible that using a single function with 20 unrelated values is your actual problem, and you should use a different design.

Comment: @Bergi the use case is pretty simple. I get JSON from the server, as one part of it is a number, which corresponds to specific message. To decode it I have to do this if/else thing.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: But what does this correspondence *mean*? It's not just a message id, otherwise you wouldn't have multiple numbers per message. Why doesn't the server send the message itself?

Comment: @Bergi I updated the question with explanation

Comment: @SalvadorDali: I see. For that use case, a (JSON?) config object that maps ids to messages and/or categories, similar to what GameAlchemist proposed, seems to be the way to go. Btw, "thin client" usually refers to thin logic (and heavy data transmission), not to thin bandwidth :-)

Answer (score 4):

Best way to handle it would be to use an array with the steps and associated values. You also need a default value  :

```
var default = 'aValue';
var steps   = [2, 'something', 6, 'anotherThing', 8, 'this', 10, 'that', ... ];
```

Then define a function that uses this array

```
function findSmallestMatch(val, default, steps) {
     for (var i=0; i<steps.length; i+=2) if (val<steps[i]) return steps[i+1];
     return default;
}
```

Use it with :

```
var res = findSmallestMatch ( 5, default, steps );  // returns 'anotherThing
```

---

Edit : 
   If you know your input is a positive integer within a 'reasonable' range, you can pre-fill
a map with the values :

```
var default = 'aValue';
var steps   = [2, 'something', 6, 'anotherThing', 8, 'this', 10, 'that', ... ];
var matchMap = [];
for (var i=0; i<maximumValue; i+=1) 
     matchMap[i] = findSmallestMatch(i, default, steps);
```

later you can use simply with :

```
var res = matchMap[value];
```

Comment: +1. You also might consider using a binary search on the array to improve performance (which would have been quite ugly to do with the if-statements).

Comment: @Bergi : I think you'd be right about binary search in any compiled language, but branching cost is so high in Javascript that it would most likely speed *down* things to do a search for a small array like O.P.'s (limit ? <50 ? ). For a big array, binary search would be the way to go, sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var data = [[2, 'somethingX'], [4, 'somethingY'], ......];
var b = 'somethingZ'; // default value

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (a < data[i][0]) {
     b = data[i][1];
     break;
  }
}
```