# What does this JavaScript object array expression {}[] mean?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the following JavaScript code I have found (and actually use) in Masonry:

```
var docElem = document.documentElement;
var transitionProp = typeof docElem.style.transition == 'string' ?
    'transition' : 'WebkitTransition';
var transitionEndEvent = {
  WebkitTransition: 'webkitTransitionEnd',
  transition: 'transitionend'
}[ transitionProp ];
```

Does the expression {}[] mean, that the transitionProp variable is added to transitionEndEvent object? 
And is the Expression typeof docElem.style.transition someway of finding out if css transition is supported?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `{}` creates an object .. `[x]` returns the property that has the value of `x`

Comment: It's [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation). It allows you to refer to a property of an object with a variable.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383798/using-object-literal-rather-than-switch-statement

Comment: The last six lines do exactly the same as `var transitionEndEvent = typeof docElem.style.transition == 'string' ? 'transitionend' : 'webkitTransitionEnd';` ... someone's just being "clever"

Comment: Thank you all! Helped me a lot... I agree Jaromanda. Much to complicated for a simple thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's returning that particular element of the object.

For example:

```
var obj = { key: 'value' };
var val = obj['key']);
```

Could be shortened to:

```
var val = { key: 'value' }['key'];
```

(Obviously in this case it's pointless, but it illustrates what is happening.)

Answer (score 0):

The initial two lines,

```
var docElem = document.documentElement;
var transitionProp = typeof docElem.style.transition == 'string' ?
    'transition' : 'WebkitTransition';
```

will assign value `transition` or `WebkitTransition` to `transitionProp` .

Then you create an object and by using `[transitionProp]` it will be more like the value of `transitionProp`inside `['transition'/'WebkitTransition']`.

```
var transitionEndEventObj = {
  WebkitTransition: 'webkitTransitionEnd',
  transition: 'transitionend'
};
var transitionEndEvent = transitionEndEventObj[ transitionProp ];
```

in other terms it will look either like this

```
var transitionEndEvent = transitionEndEventObj[ 'transition'];
```

or

```
var transitionEndEvent = transitionEndEventObj['WebkitTransition'];
```

Answer (score 0):

here `transitionEndEvent` will contain:

`'webkitTransitionEnd'` if `transitionProp == 'WebkitTransition'` or

`'transitionend'` if `transitionProp == 'transition'`

Answer (score 0):

To add some property to JSON we use

```
object["property"] = value;
```

So the above lines in your code is written to access the property name transitionProp from the object.

So the variable transitionEndEvent will hold the value of transitionProp property.

```
var transitionEndEvent = {
  WebkitTransition: 'webkitTransitionEnd',
  transition: 'transitionend'
}[ transitionProp ];
```

Comment: There's no JSON here.